# Animate font-awesome stack to spin icon on hover

Tags: css, css-animations, font-awesome

I have a simple font awesome icon stack:

```
<span class="icon-stack">
  <i class="icon-circle icon-stack-base"></i>
  <i class="icon-flag icon-light"></i>
</span>
```

I am trying to think of a way to animate the icon on hover, using css alone. The effect I am trying to achieve is similar to the "social sharing" images here: 
http://demo.rocknrolladesigns.com/html/jarvis/shortcodes.html. (Apologies, you'll need to scroll as there is no #anchor).

This site uses offset on png images, but I'd like to try this with font-awesome and some CSS3. Any ideas?

**EDIT**

Attempted (failed!) implementation here: http://bootply.com/66542

Comment: Have you tried implementing anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, have a fixed height/width on the `.icon-stack`. Have the exact same height on both child elements. This will cause the child elements to float below each other. From there on it's just a matter of animating it on hover. I used a negative top margin on hover to make it "scroll" up. The negative top margin has to be equal to the child elements height. To top it off I just used CSS transitions to animate it.

Toggle `overflow: hidden;` on/off to see how it works better.

Comment: I'm having trouble getting this to apply to the font-awesome stack; http://bootply.com/66542, can you see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @RobM The CSS i wrote on codepen is in LESS syntax, i don't believe bootply supports less compiling. You can copy the raw CSS from codepen by clicking on the title of the CSS box (where it says CSS (LESS). Copy that and give it another try.

Comment: @RobM I fixed one box: http://bootply.com/66543 You can probably figure it out from there on.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe this is what you are looking for?

http://jsfiddle.net/VVeTw/

```
<span class="icon-stack">
<i class="icon-circle icon-stack-base"></i>
<i class="icon-flag icon-light first"></i>
<i class="icon-flag icon-light second"></i>
</span>
```

and the CSS

```
span {
    font-size: 50px;
    color: #fff;
}
.icon-stack-base {
    color: white;
}
.icon-light {
    color: black;
}
.icon-stack, .icon-stack-base, .icon-flag {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease 0s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease 0s;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s ease 0s;
    transition: all 0.2s ease 0s;
    overflow: hidden;
}
i {
    height: 60px;
    width: 60px;
}
.icon-stack:hover {
    color: black;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.icon-stack:hover .icon-stack-base {
    color: #5b9a68;
}
.icon-stack:hover .first {
    margin-top: -80px;
}
.icon-stack:hover .second {
    color: white;
}
```